# Fastest method to perform bilinear interpolation on geolocated, irregularly spaced longitude/latitude grids using python?

Tags: python, arrays, grid, latitude-longitude, interpolation

I have two irregular grids of the form `np.array[i,j,k]`.  They represent longitude and latitude arrays: `lons[135,90,4]` and `lats[135,90,4]`.  At each `i,j` coordinate I have data that is sub-divided into a 9x8 pixel grid.  The `k` values in the lon/lat arrays correspond to the lon/lat values at the 4 corners of each 9x8 sub-grid.  The 1st array element is the upper-left pixel.  The 2nd element is the upper-right pixel. The 3rd and 4th elements refer to the lower-left and lower-right pixels, respectively.  Here is an illustration of a grid point located at `i,j` on the `135,90` grid: 
                              **j**
     **k=0**                                       **k=1**
         0
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      0|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      1|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      2|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      3|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**i**     4|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      5|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      6|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      7|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
      8|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
     **k=2**                                       **k=3**
I have the data for each sub-grid pixel in an array of the form `data[135,90,9,8]` and I want to plot the data on a map using something like: `plt.pcolormesh(lons,lats,data)`.
So far I've written a loop that reshapes the data into a 2D array: `new_data[1215,720]`

```
# Note: 135*9 = 1215, 90*8 = 720
new_data = np.zeros((1215,720))
n,m,i,j=0,0,0,0
for i in range(135):
    for j in range(90):
        new_data[n:n+9,m:m+8] = data[i,j,:,:]
        m = m + 8
    m = 0
    n = n + 9
```

I now need to apply a bilinear interpolation to the 9x8 sub-grid for each `i,j` grid point using the 4 corner lon/lat values (i.e. the `k` values).  Essentially I need the lon/lat arrays in the form: `new_lons[1215,720]`, `new_lats[1215,720]`, in order to plot with `pcolormesh`.

**What is the most efficient (fastest) method for applying this type of interpolation?  And how would I apply it in this case?**

There are lots of interpolation questions, but I haven't seen one that involves the interpolation of a sub-grid for each point located on an irregularly spaced lon/lat grid.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've since figured out a solution to my question, so hopefully this helps someone out there one day...

To re-grid the lat/lons I used a bilinear interpolation with `imresize`:

```
from scipy.misc import imresize

new_data = np.zeros((1215,720))
new_lons = np.zeros((1215,720))
new_lats = np.zeros((1215,720))

n,m=0,0
for i in range(135):
    for j in range(90):
        new_data[n:n+9,m:m+8] = data[i,j,:,:]
        new_lons[n:n+9,m:m+8] = imresize(lons[i,j,:].reshape(2,2), (9,8), mode='F', interp='bilinear')
        new_lats[n:n+9,m:m+8] = imresize(lats[i,j,:].reshape(2,2), (9,8), mode='F', interp='bilinear')
        m = m + 8
    m = 0
    n = n + 9
```